# Different border bottom for links with bold text

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On this page (http://nate.fm/testing/) you can see that the  text link's bottom border gets pushed down. Can anyone tell me where I can change that in the CSS?

Comment: You could use text-decoration: underline; instead of border-bottom. But then  you cannot change the color of the underline.

Comment: Yeah, I really want to be able to change the color and the spacing (my current link underline is supposed to be a little lower than text-decoration, but not _this_ low. ;)

Comment: It seems to be a problem with this particular font. With another font, the spacing is the same with bold and normal text. EDIT: For example, .post-content a {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #eee;
    font-family: arial;
}

Comment: @cjs1978 Different fonts will have different heights for glyphs depending on how the font author designed it (there will be different padding on top and bottom of each glyph/character). Its just a characteristic of the font-family.

Comment: @zgood Yes, "problem" was the wrong word to use here, you are completely right.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `<a>` tag to `display: inline-block;` then reduce the `line-height`.

Something like this maybe:

```
.post-content a {
    line-height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant solution. I stand corrected re: my comments above.

Comment: Should I do that only for <strong> text so that it doesn't mess up my non-strong text links? Basically, I want both <strong> and non-<strong> text links to have the same underline (the one I currently have for my non-<strong> links.)

Comment: I don't think it should mess up anything, but if you want to be safe you you can change the css selector to `.post-content strong a` to target only links inside strong tags or create a class with just that style and apply it to the elements you want.

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you. I did have to use the ".post-content strong a" however.

Answer (score 0):

```
.post-content a {
    /* border-bottom: 3px solid #eee; */
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use text-decoration.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer, that says what that code does, or how it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

They are using `border-bottom` along with `line-height`, the `line-height` property causes the effect of "pushing" down the border you are mentioning

`.post-content a {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #eee;
    line-height: 160%;
}`

Comment: Should I reduce the line-height just for the bold text, then? If so, how?

Comment: In the example page, both `<a>` tags have the same line-height, what makes the difference in space that you see is that `<strong>` tag has a `font-weight` of 700, so the anchor inside inherits it.

Comment: Are you recommending the code that you included above? It didn't seem to make a difference when I used it.

Comment: I'm not recommending it, it's the code that uses the example you are asking how to mimic. You can check it using your browser's inspector.